# OnEdit(e) Google Sheets to clear adjacent cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the below code to run, and it won't trigger.
The goal is to clear B2, when B1 is changed

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Quotes V2" && e.range(1,2) )
  {
    e.range(2,2).clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

- [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger works only when the **user** changes the value of a cell. If the value is changed by a script or formula, then `onEdit` won't work for you.
- Familiarize yourself with the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). This expression is wrong `e.range(2,2)`. Because `e.range` is not a function but a range object.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Quotes V2" && e.range.getA1Notation()=='B1' )
  {
    sh.getRange('B2').clear();
  }
}
```